# Wordpress- MySQL said:' Unknown column 'users.ID' in 'on clause'

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I'm trying to pivot two tables together for displaying backend user info on an admin only portion of my wordpress site, and cant get past the error "MySQL said: Unknown column 'u.ID' in 'on clause'"
The data structure is correct, but I cant seem to get past this.

```
select u.ID as name,
um.*
from users as u, usermeta as um
join (
   select um.umeta_id,
   max(case when meta_key='nickname' then meta_value end)as nickname,
   max(case when meta_key='first_name' then meta_value end)as first_name
   from usermeta as um
   group by um.umeta_id)
um on u.ID=um.umeta_id
```

Comment: Dont mix , (old join syntax) and JOIN syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two suggestions:

1) don't mix the old school comma join syntax with the newer JOIN keyword syntax

2) make table aliases *unique* within a statement (don't reuse the `um` alias)

---

I don't think we need two joins to the usermeta table. I suspect we are wanting to return a resultset like the one that would be returned by this query:

```
SELECT u.id           AS name
     , m.nickname     AS nickname
     , m.first_name   AS first_name
  FROM users u
  LEFT
  JOIN (SELECT um.umeta_id
             , MAX(CASE WHEN um.meta_key='nickname'   THEN um.meta_value END) AS nickname
             , MAX(CASE WHEN um.meta_key='first_name' THEN um.meta_value END) AS first_name
          FROM usermeta um
         GROUP
            BY um.umeta_id
       ) m
    ON m.umeta_id = u.id
 ORDER BY u.id
```

That's just a guess. Without a specification, or example data and expected result, we're just guessing.

---

**FOLLOWUP**

As an alternative to the join, we can use correlated subqueries in the SELECT list. For example:

```
SELECT u.id AS name
     , ( SELECT umn.meta_value
           FROM usermeta umn
          WHERE umn.umeta_id = u.id
            AND umn.meta_key='nickname'
          ORDER BY umn.meta_value DESC
          LIMIT 1
       ) AS nickname
     , ( SELECT umn.meta_value
           FROM usermeta umn
          WHERE umn.umeta_id = u.id
            AND umn.meta_key='first_name'
          ORDER BY umn.meta_value DESC
          LIMIT 1
       ) AS first_name
  FROM users u
 ORDER BY u.id
```

For a reasonable number of rows returned by the outer query, we can get reasonable performance, as long as we have suitable index defined on usermeta table, leading columns of `(umeta_id,meta_key)`. Ideally a covering index that also includes `meta_value`.

Those subqueries are going to be executed for each and *every* row returned by the outer query, so those can really bog down performance if we're returning a lot of rows.

Comment: Sorry, its giving me good data on the first result ID from the user table, but it is not completing for all rows.

Comment: The query in this answer should be returning *every* row from `users` table, along with a matching nickname and first_name found in usermeta table. The nickname and first_name will be NULL when a matching row isn't found. (The naming of the umeta_id column strikes me as a bit odd for a foreign key referencing `users(id)`. Does the `umeta_id` column contain an id value from users? Is that the right join condition? The join predicate in this query was copied from the original query... I don't have any example data, the only specification I have is the erroneous SQL in the the question.)